# Understanding bracketless for/if combination in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following code segment:

```
for ( SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES* it = ptg->Groups; end != it; ++it )
    if ( EqualSid( it->Sid, pAdminSid ) )
        break;

bIsAdmin = end != it;
```

Irritatingly, when step-by-step debugging in VS, the final line is executed with each of the for iterations. I was expecting the above code segment would behave identical to:

```
for ( SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES* it = ptg->Groups; end != it; ++it ) {
    if ( EqualSid( it->Sid, pAdminSid ) )
        break;
}

bIsAdmin = end != it;
```

Can somebody explain why this is not the case?

Comment: And you're right to assume that. However there's something else, that's odd. You declare 'it' only in your for-loop, however it is still declared at 'bIsAdmin'? How does that work?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium This is part of a foreign piece of code which I am trying to understand. In fact, "it" was not declared at bIsAdmin. I moved the declaration out of the for loop which fixed that particular problem. But the for-weirdness persists.

Comment: Have you checked, that it's not just your debugger fooling you? Have you checked, that the value is actually changing? How about that, set `bIsAdmin` to `true` before the loop. Naturally, during the first iteration, it would set it to `false` since 'end' hasn't been reached yet.

Comment: yea i suspect it's just syncing the line number incorrectly, and it's really not actually executing that line

Comment: weirdnesses like stepping through code and the debugger being off are usually a result of either 1) Compiling for Release or a build flavor with optimizations enabled. OR  2) You didn't actually do a clean build and/or your modified source code isn't the same as what you are actually debugging.  Do a clean DEBUG build and make sure the EXE and DLLs getting used are the ones you built. Look at the timestamp on these files to make sure

Comment: As for "it" being accessible outside of the FOR loop.  As per MSDN: "By default, under /Ze, a variable declared in a for loop remains in scope until the for loop's enclosing scope ends. /Zc:forScope enables standard behavior of variables declared in for loops without needing to specify /Za."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80153d8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @RefugnicEternium You are right. The line is highlighted in the debugger but not executed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is "only one semicolon", there is no need for braces. Although I'm one of those people that like to put extra braces in my code, just in case. It never hurts, really...

As to the stepping behaviour, I've seen this too in both Visual Studio and Eclipse debuggers. I think it reflects the "end of the loop has to be on some line" - so if there is no ending brace, the last line within the loop contains the "is the loop finished" step. Annoying it is indeed.